# Can I prevent RestSharp from decoding a gzip response?

Tags: gzip, restsharp

I'm trying to use RestSharp as a transparent proxy between a client and a resource that send data gzipped. Obviously I don't want to have my proxy waste resources on decoding and re-encoding the gzipped responses, but it seems like this is done automatically.

Is there some way to tell RestSharp not to decode any gzipped responses so that I could just read the raw gzip bytes and return these to the client?